# Segmentation Fault upon exit of QGIS map canvas

Tags: pyqgis, qgsmapcanvas

I have simplified my original code. My code is very similar to [Pyqgis' cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html). I am simply loading one VALID layer to QgsMapCanvas and then displaying it. Everything is displayed corectly etc. Problem is, everytime I exit out of the QgsMapCanvas GUI, my code then shows a segmentation fault (core dumped) message. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


def main():
    # initiate canvas for debugging purposes
    # supply path to qgis install location
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
    # create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
    # second argument to False disables the GUI
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    # load providers
    app.initQgis()

    # create Qt mapCanvas object
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.transparent)
    # enable this for smooth rendering
    canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)

    # create vector layer object
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('BUAARE.shp', 'layer', 'ogr')

    if layer.isValid():
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])

    canvas.show()
    app.exec_()

    # exit qgis
    app.exitQgis()
main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Something isn't being cleaned up from memory right...

If I have a main routine that creates a `QgsApplication`, works with a canvas, and then calls `exitQgis`, then I get a seg fault after calling it. Note that I don't do any layer stuff here, which simplifies things to:

```
def badmain():
    app = QgsApplication([],True)
    app.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
    app.initQgis()
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.show()
    app.exec_()
    app.exitQgis()
    print "exited"
badmain()
print "Ending"
```

It prints "exited" but not "Ending".

But if I create a `QgsApplication` object and pass it to a function, it doesn't seg fault:

```
def okmain(app):
    app.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
    app.initQgis()
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.show()
    app.exec_()
    print "exited"

app = QgsApplication([], True)
okmain(app)
app.exitQgis()
print "Ending"
```

I can even put the `app.exitQgis()` inside the function, as long as I don't create it in the function.

Weirdly, I can create an `app` in a function and pass it to another function:

```
def main():
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    okmain(app) # as above
    app.exitQgis()
    print "Ending"

main()
```

and this works without seg faults. How much of `okmain` I need to pull into `main` to recreate the crash with `badmain` I don't yet know... But a quick test seems to indicate its to do with the scope of the `canvas`.

So I suspect that when your `main` exits something tries to clean up the `canvas` object because it hasn't noticed that it's gone out of scope, but then why does my last example work, since `canvas` is out of scope when `okmain` returns? This might be some terribly subtle bug somewhere, but hopefully this will give you something to work round it. Certainly if you take your code out of a `main` function and just have it with indent=0 as a script, it runs fine.