# Using exitQgis() in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

After infinitely many attempts to fix this, I can't prevent python to crash (segmentation fault) when scripting in QGIS. I am using the **qgis2** build from **osgeo4mac**, installed with homebrew on El Capitan. I am interested in running something like:

```
from qgis.core import *

app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()

# DO STUFF HERE

app.exitQgis()
```

The above script will work in the sense that all the STUFF I want it to do will be properly executed, and I believe that `app.exitQgis()` will also remove the data provider and layer registries from memory. However, python will crash unexpectedly on quit because of a SIGSEGV error.

Upon reading [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/206548) from [spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman), I managed to avoid the crash with the following structure:

```
from qgis.core import *

def main(app):
    # DO STUFF HERE 
    return

app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
main(app)
app.exitQgis()
```

Although I have no idea why, the above runs smoothly. I however encounter the SIGSEGV error again when I try to run something more involved, using the `Processing` toolbox:

```
from qgis.core import *
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

def main(app):
    # DO STUFF HERE 
    Processing.runAlgorithm(...) # DO MORE INVOLVED STUFF
    return

app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
Processing.initialize()
main(app)
app.exitQgis()
```

Again, the above script will properly execute everything, but python will crash on quit.

I am out of solutions and I was wondering what would happen if I simply omit the `app.exitQgis()`  line from the above script. This would do all what needs to be done, avoid the crash, but would not "clean up".

Is this a terrible idea?

Will this use up all my RAM if I run it multiple times?

***Update:***

The segfault seems to be triggered  by objects loaded in memory. For example this will crash:

```
from qgis.core import *
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
layer = QgsVectorLayer('shapefile.shp', 'all', 'ogr')
app.exitQgis()
```

But this will not:

```
from qgis.core import *
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()
layer = QgsVectorLayer('shapefile.shp', 'all', 'ogr')
del layer # CLEANING UP HERE
app.exitQgis()
```

which is why a function structure also prevents the crash: loaded layers are local variables within the function environment. Regarding the use of the `Processing` toolbox, the number of objects in memory does indeed increase after the use of `Processing.runAlgorithm(...)`. Using the garbage collector module, `import gc`, I find that `gc.get_count()` increases right after an algorithm from `Processing` is used.

---

some details on the crash. the python ouput produced by the `app.exitQgis()` line:

```
src/core/auth/qgsauthmethodregistry.cpp: 154: (~QgsAuthMethodRegistry)[936ms] cleanup: Basic
src/core/auth/qgsauthmethodregistry.cpp: 154: (~QgsAuthMethodRegistry) [0ms] cleanup: Identity-Cert
src/core/auth/qgsauthmethodregistry.cpp: 154: (~QgsAuthMethodRegistry) [0ms] cleanup: PKI-PKCS#12
src/core/auth/qgsauthmethodregistry.cpp: 154: (~QgsAuthMethodRegistry) [0ms] cleanup: PKI-Paths
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [3ms] cleanup:DB2
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:WFS
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [1ms] cleanup:arcgisfeatureserver
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:arcgismapserver
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [1ms] cleanup:delimitedtext
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:gdal
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:gpx
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [1ms] cleanup:memory
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:mssql
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [1ms] cleanup:ogr
src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 41: (~QgsOgrConnPool) [0ms] Entering.
src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 41: (~QgsOgrConnPool) [0ms] Leaving.
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:ows
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:postgres
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:spatialite
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:virtual
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:wcs
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [1ms] cleanup:wms
src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 36: (QgsOgrConnPool) [78ms] Entering.
src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 36: (QgsOgrConnPool) [0ms] Leaving.
[Finished in 7.8s with exit code -11]
```

the OSX crash report:

```
Date/Time:             2017-08-03 13:06:51.003 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        08F4C3E0-65A6-5136-C3BB-0D146F412EAC


Time Awake Since Boot: 47000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libgdal.20.dylib                0x00000001178771f4 OGR_DS_GetDriver + 14
1   libogrprovider.so               0x0000000126408000 QgsOgrProviderUtils::OGRDestroyWrapper(void*) + 40
2   libogrprovider.so               0x00000001263ee5e4 QgsOgrProvider::close() + 66
3   libogrprovider.so               0x00000001263ee348 QgsOgrProvider::~QgsOgrProvider() + 164
4   libogrprovider.so               0x00000001263ee694 QgsOgrProvider::~QgsOgrProvider() + 14
5   org.qgis.qgis2_core             0x0000000114ebdfc6 QgsVectorLayer::~QgsVectorLayer() + 58
6   _core.so                        0x0000000114077a30 sipQgsVectorLayer::~sipQgsVectorLayer() + 14
7   _core.so                        0x0000000114079c41 release_QgsVectorLayer(void*, int) + 66
8   sip.so                          0x0000000108ac48c1 forgetObject + 114
9   sip.so                          0x0000000108ac46b1 sipWrapper_dealloc + 14
10  org.python.python               0x00000001070dc257 subtype_dealloc + 667
11  org.python.python               0x00000001070bbee2 dict_dealloc + 129
12  org.python.python               0x00000001070bd13d insertdict_by_entry + 249
13  org.python.python               0x00000001070bba5a insertdict + 51
14  org.python.python               0x00000001070bb221 dict_set_item_by_hash_or_entry + 40
15  org.python.python               0x00000001070bfd78 _PyModule_Clear + 177
16  org.python.python               0x00000001071218ce PyImport_Cleanup + 958
17  org.python.python               0x000000010712c2ec Py_Finalize + 297
18  org.python.python               0x000000010713e153 Py_Main + 2455
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000107a595ad start + 1
```

Comment: Can you share any details on the crash?

Comment: @StephenRauch done!

Comment: @Vlad - Try using `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/path/to/qgis", True)`, `app = QApplication([], False)`, `QgsApplication.initQgis()` instead of your `app = QgsApplication([], False)`, `app.initQgis()`.

Comment: @Joseph the path to my QGIS app is set in my bash_profile so I don't think I need to specify it in my python code. Regardless, I just tried what you propose and I still get the seg fault.

Comment: @Joseph helped me with a similar problem similar here [Why does the QgsFeatureIterator crash in my stand alone script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153210/why-does-the-qgsfeatureiterator-crash-in-my-stand-alone-script) and I added app.exit() but I see that its now app.exitQgis() as per [The api class](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsApplication.html). I wonder when that changed?

Comment: Using `app.exit()` instead of `exitQgis()` stopped the crashing for me

Comment: After searching for hours this "offtopic" thread had the right answer! THANK YOU! exit() fixed the issue for us, whereas exitQgis() crashed the script.